# Which algorithm can be used to partition graph to make each partitioned group(or component)'s value equal or balance?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph-algorithm, mathematical-optimization, partitioning

Let's assume graph is composed of nodes with values and undirected edges.
 
I would like to partition graph into ***several groups that I choose*** as meeting a condition that ***each partitioned group has similar or same sum of values*** that node has.
 
 
Could you recommend which algorithms can be used to partition the graph with meeting the condition that I mentioned?
I would appreciate it even more if you attach an algorithm implemented with python or java.
(For your understanding, we have attached pictures and data types.)

```
<Data information>
[node_id]: n_1, n_2, n_3 ,, etc
[node_value]: 10, 5, 20,, etc
[node_adjacency_data] : Please refer to the attached picture.
[node_latitude]: 37.25201, 37.25211, 37.25219,, etc
[node_longitude]: 127.10195, 127.11321, 127.11377,, etc
```

[image: this is a example of graph here]

[image: this is adjacent data of above graph here]

Comment: Must the subgraphs induced by each element of the partition be connected?

Comment: This is definitely NP-Hard since you can solve the integer [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem#Recurrence_relation) by creating a complete graph with one node for each number in that list.

Comment: @AlexReinking Thanks for your reply. Subgraph which has similar sum of values need to be connected. I read your link about partition problem. I think it's very similar to my case except it partitions to 2 subgraph. Can it be changed to partition multi sub graph rather than 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, this problem is NP-Hard, so you will not be able to get perfect solutions to this problem. However, there is actually a good body of research designed to partition graphs in this way. Start your search by looking up *vertex weighted graph partitioning*.

The most famous algorithm for partitioning graphs in this way is [METIS](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pingali/CS395T/2009fa/papers/metis.pdf), and there is a [good Python wrapper](http://metis.readthedocs.io/en/latest) for the optimized C implementation (which you have to build/install separately). It takes either networkx graphs or simple adjacency lists as input.

METIS takes a graph with weighted vertices and edges and returns up to the given number of partitions while minimizing the weight of the edges being cut. You will still have to pick how many parts you want to break your graph into.

Here's some example code using the Python METIS library to solve the example problem you gave:

```py
import networkx as nx
import metis

# Set up graph structure
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([ (0,1), (0,2), (0,3), (1, 2), (3, 4) ])

# Add node weights to graph
for i, value in enumerate([1,3,2,4,3]):
    G.node[i]['node_value'] = value

# tell METIS which node attribute to use for 
G.graph['node_weight_attr'] = 'node_value' 

# Get at MOST two partitions from METIS
(cut, parts) = metis.part_graph(G, 2) 
# parts == [0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

# Assuming you have PyDot installed, produce a DOT description of the graph:
colors = ['red', 'blue']
for i, part in enumerate(parts):
    G.node[i]['color'] = colors[part]
nx.nx_pydot.write_dot(G, 'example.dot')
```

We can then use GraphViz to visualize the partition:

[image: Visualization of graph in question]

Which is the same partition you gave in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think your answer will really help me. Then, is it possible like cutting into 2 parts while sum of values of node in subgraph is similar?

Comment: Oh, oops. I forgot the line where I add weights to the vertices. I'll do that now.

Comment: METIS will take vertex weights into account when producing a partition, but since it's a heuristic, there aren't any real guarantees. If you need better partitions than METIS provides, then you'll be advancing the state of the art.

Comment: I really appreciate your help! I will study more for the balancing the values of node. Thanks for your kindnesss answer :)